# Assistance with a 4 table Join operation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, join, left-join

In the attempt of being as clear as posible, I have 4 tables in my database as it follows

1. Join_Contrato_Medidor

   - ID_Union (identity)
   - ID_Contrato
   - ID_Medidor
   - Omitido (filger ?)
2. Promedios

   - ID_Contrato
   - ID_Medidor
   - ID_Marchamo
   - {Info I want}
3. Medidores

   - ID_Medidor
   - ID_Dispensario (filter ?)
4. Marchamo

   - ID_Marchamo

My current SQL Statement...

SELECT         {Promedios.LI_1, Promedios.LF_1, Promedios.Total_1, Promedios.Qva_1, ...}

FROM            (((

Join_Contrato_Medidor LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Promedios ON Join_Contrato_Medidor.ID_Contrato = Promedios.ID_Contrato)

LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Medidores ON Join_Contrato_Medidor.ID_Medidor = Medidores.ID_Medidor)

LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Marchamo ON Promedios.ID_Marchamo = Marchamo.ID_Marchamo)

WHERE        (Join_Contrato_Medidor.ID_Contrato = ?) AND (Medidores.ID_Dispensario = ?) AND (Join_Contrato_Medidor.Omitido <> TRUE)

The output im obtaining:

Information Columns              |     Omitido            |        ID_Union

1. Info    |       False        |    806
2. Info    |       False         |   806
3. Info     |      False         |   806
4. Info   |       False        |    806

**I wanted to include an image but I cannot do so until I have more reputation :( **

I have those 4 tables that I am Joining right now.  I am currently getting all the columns desired to be output in the query, but the thing is that I would only like to get those records in which --Join_Contrato_Medidor.Omitido <> true-- instead of getting ALL records that match the ID_Contrato and ID_Dispensario conditions.

As a sample, I am outputing ID_Union, which is the identity field for the Join_Contrato_Medidor.  It is marking all the records with a single ID_Union, which happens to be the only one record out of the 4 that has Omitido <> true.  Also, the latest 3 records have their Omitido field set to **true** in the database nevertheless it is showing false in the query result.

If the question is unclear, please post me for clarification.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the query looks like you need data only from Promedios table whose child records in Join_Contrato_Medidor matching your condition. Is that sounds right?

Comment: If my English serves well that would be completely correct.  The Join_Contrato_Medidor table is only used to determine which records should be included.  It sounds from your comment as if that was somehow the problem :3

Answer (score 0):

After working on other things until I had to face this issue again, I am back checking it. Your comment led me to try and see if switching the order of the tables would do the job, and it did! Thank you very much.

I started asking for hte Promedios table first  and the nperform the rest of the query. This gave me access to the exact information that I wanted. Moreover, all the following queries I created them following this order and lead to better shorter queries.